# How to pass Strong parameters to Model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it has a way to pass Strong parameters from Controller to Model

My point is passing param1 and param2 which contain in strong_params to The Model
after that **I want to access to puts param1 and param2 that contain in strong_param which received from controller**

*Assume that I have value in param1 and param2 already*

In Controller

```
def action
   @sender = someModel.new()
   @sender.var_tunnel(strong_params)
end

private
def strong_params
   params.require(:stp).permit(:param1, :param2)
end
```

In someModel

```
def var_tunnel(stong_params)
    puts param1
    puts param2
end
```

Thanks for Advance

Comment: what you want to achieve is very confusing..

Comment: Are you aware of `Hash` class of Ruby ? If you do, then inspect `stong_params`, like `stong_params.class`.. and then look for the Ruby API of the resultant class, to understand how can you access the values from the `stong_params` variable.. Please do what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can access to the params in stong_params in your model like a Hash. So

```
def var_tunel(stong_params)
    puts stong_params[:param1]
    puts stong_params[:param2]
end
```